# HTML4 fallback gives trailing dots in URL

Tags: javascript, history.js, html4

I'm building a new portfolio for my company using history.js and pushState,
http://saturate.se

The site needs to be HTML4 compatible and while I manage to get things working with pushState I run into problems creating the fragment identifier equivalents. If you try and navigate the site in IE <10 you will see that the identifier gets a trailing dot added to it. Also, when trying to access links in subdirectories the URL seems to miss a "/" after the identifier (for example, "http://saturate.se/work/example" turns into http://saturate.se/#work/example".
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I haven't tried anything really for the hashtag part, just looking for directions (tips, tutorials etc.). From my point of view the documentation for history.js is very poor.

Comment: A hashtag is a keyword flagged for searching on Twitter. Please don't use the term to refer to fragment identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

> just looking for directions (tips, tutorials etc.)

Forget about using the fragment identifier to track history.

- You'll be cursed to support it for ever more (other people's link to your pages won't go away)
- The server never sees it, so you'll suffer the Flash Of Default Page that you get on Twitter
- A standard, better replacement already exists so it is dying already

If the browser supports the history API, then use it.

If it doesn't, fallback to non-Ajax instead of non-history-API (which is [what Github does](https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider)).

Comment: If I understand it correctly you mean - get rid of the fragment identifiers altogether? I was considering that, the site will function properly without them (with some scrolling adjustments).